# Dynamic CheckBoxFor with some disables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I'm trying to create a dynamic CheckBoxFor where some items are disabled.

This is disabling everything:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Checked, new { @disabled = "disabled"})
```

I was trying to create something like this without success:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Checked, new{ @disabled = @(Model.Disable ? "disabled" : "")})
```

One note, my Model has a property called Disabled and another Checked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not working because the disabled attribute disables a CheckBox regardless of what it's value is.

I'm not sure how to do this in one line, but here's one solution:

```
@if(Model.Disabled)
{ 
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Checked, new { @disabled = "disabled"})
}
else
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Checked)
}
```

A potential Html Helper Extension:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression,
        object htmlAttributes,
        bool isDisabled)
{
    var dic = htmlAttributes.GetType()
             .GetProperties()
             .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(htmlAttributes, null));

    if (isDisabled)
        dic["disabled"] = "disabled";

    return helper.CheckBoxFor(expression, dic);
}
```

Comment: And if I want to define the checked/not checked. A lot of 'if' will create a difficult to read code

Comment: @Custódio I edited my answer. That said, Checked/not checked is already contained within your Checked variable, so you shouldn't ever have to define that explicitly.

Comment: @JonathanGreenstreet - You should post a new answer, not attempt to rewrite this one.